# How to create two dimensional array in Promela?

Tags: matrix, promela, spin

To create matrix in C we need to write:

```
int[][] a = {{1,2,3},{1,2,3},{1,2,3}}
```

How can I create a matrix in Promela?

Comment: Show your effort please.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the [docs](http://spinroot.com/spin/Man/arrays.html):

> Multidimensional arrays can be constructed indirectly with the use of `typedef` definitions.

Also from the [docs](http://spinroot.com/spin/Man/typedef.html):

> **EXAMPLES**
>
> The first example shows **how to declare a two-dimensional array** of elements of type byte with a `typedef`.
>
> ```
> typedef array { /* typedefs must be global */
>     byte aa[4]
> };
> init {
>     array a[8];   /* 8x4 = 32 bytes total */
>     a[3].aa[1] = 5
> }
> ```

A better approach is to use [one-dimensional arrays](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58744199/all-possible-knight-moving-on-a-chessboard-in-promela).